# Which one is correct: "what did he do" or "what did he does"?

Tags: questions, do-support, subject-auxiliary-inversion

I am confused about how to use "what did he do" and "what did he does".

I want to ask one friend what another friend does.

Comment: The "do/does/did" that is used to form questions and negatives is **always** followed by the simple form ('infinitive') of the verb, and not by any other form.

Answer (score 4):

Of your two example sentences the first is correct

> What did he do?

is the question for *something* he did in the past.

> What **does** he do?

is the question for *something* in the present.

the second one sentence is the answer to the first in the present and needs to be slightly changed

> what he does *(is)*